# Thunderbold to HDMI ---> HDMI Switch ---> Saeco projector = No Video

Tags: video, recommendation, hdmi

I've the following hardware and a problem getting things work.

1. projector Sanyo PLV-Z800
2. DeLock 87498 HDMI 1.3 Switch
3. MacBook Pro 2010 just with miniDisplay Port
4. MacBook Pro 2011 with Thunderbold Port
5. Lenovo ThinkPad with normal Displayport

When I try to connect my (3) MacBook Pro 2010 through my (2) HDMI Switch to my (1) projector everything works fine.

Problem:

When I try to connect my (4) MacBook Pro 2011 through my (2) HDMI Switch to my (1) projector I don't get a signal on my projector.

When I try to connect my (5) Thinkpad through my (2) HDMI Switch to my (1) projector I don't get a signal on my projector either.

I've tried to find out which hdmi versions my hardware is working with.

- The Projector seems to have the HDMI version 1.3b
- The HDMI Swtich seems to have the HDMI version 1.3
- I don't know, which versions my Macbooks have

Is there anyone who can tell me if my Switch is problem? So I just want to know if the HDMI version 1.3 doesn't support the newer standards.

Can anyone recommend me a nice and affordable HDMI Switch where my setup will work with. 
I want to buy this one: `Aten CS1792 HDMI KVMP Switch (2-polig, 2x HDMI, 2X USB)`.

Answer (score 1):

There are no real differences between HDMI 1.3 and 1.3b so I would blame either the switch (most likely), the cables (do you have the correct ones for each device), or even the configuration settings on each machine.

- If you plug each one into the projector individually do they work? If so, it is your switch that is at fault.
- If not, try replacing the cables and connect each one to the projector - does this solve the problem? If so, the cables were the problem.
- If not, check your configuration settings for the display on each machine.

Comment: thanks for the answer, 
 
>> If you plug each one into the projector individually do they work? If so, it is your switch that is at fault.

Yes they do. 
 
>> If not, try replacing the cables and connect each one to the projector - does this solve the problem? If so, the cables were the problem.

The cables are the newer once, and this are active hdmi cables. they were not cheap ;-)

>> If not, check your configuration settings for the display on each machine.
 
on the macbooks, the settings are completely the same. 

I think I've to try with a new swtich.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how the switch is designed, it might not be sending the DDC signal back to the computers when the switch isn't set to point to them, and this could be confusing the cable-detection logic on the output ports.  When you switch the switcher to the Mac, try using the Mac's "detect displays" button (on the Displays control panel) to see if it comes to life.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that the Lenovo and 2011 MacBook support HDMI out via their displayPort?  Native DisplayPort signals are not compatible with HDMI.  What a DisplayPort to HDMI adapter actually does is simply put a DisplayPort that supports HDMI signaling in to the appropriate mode to send an HDMI signal, but it is not a required part of the DisplayPort standard.  It is possible that your devices simply do not implement HDMI signaling.

I would recommend trying to connect both non-working devices to a direct HDMI output to see if they work.  If they do, it may be that the HDMI detection does not work with the switch.  I've seen that before in cheap HDMI switches even when using native HDMI devices.  The solution then is unfortunately either a) restart the source device while that source is selected (to see if the full signal path is maintained when selected) or b) get a better HDMI switch.  It might also be possible to lock the HDMI output option on in a driver somewhere, but that would be hardware specific.